# Passing a preallocated char* buffer to a c function

Tags: c, swift, pointers, swift3

I have a function in c that receives a preallocated string and fills it with data - I'd like to call this function from swift.
I've found many examples on how to pass strings from swift to c, but I found none showing c functions that write the data on a preallocated string.

The c function:

```
int GetData(char *dataJson, int maxSize);
```

On the swift side, this code compiles, but I can't find how to preallocate `dataBuffer`

```
let dataBuffer = UnsafePointer<UInt8>
GetData(dataBuffer, 2048)
```

Is there a way to do so in Swift?

Answer (score 7):

An easy way is to pass an array as inout expression with `&`,
this calls the function with a pointer to the contiguous element
storage:

```
var dataBuffer = Array<Int8>(repeating: 0, count: 2048)
let result = GetData(&dataBuffer, numericCast(dataBuffer.count))
```

The advantage is that you don't have to manage the memory manually,
it is released automatically when `dataBuffer` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, here's the code for future reference:

```
let dataBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: 2048)
GetData(dataBuffer, 2048)
let jsonData = String(cString: dataBuffer)
```

Comment: That's correct, but you should deallocate the memory eventually, otherwise you have a memory leak.